# How do i return enumaration status if invalid password but return record if their is

Tags: c#, entity-framework, authentication

I have modified my validate to return the record if it finds one but how would I also return an enumeration type  to identify if its an incorrect password or username that the user has entered ??
eg like I have showed in the return for false password.

```
  public user isValidUser(string username, string userPassword)
  {
      try
      {
          var _currentUser = _db.users.FirstOrDefault(a => a.username == username);

          if (_currentUser != null)
          {
              string descriptedPassword = encrypt.DecryptRijndael(_currentUser.password, _currentUser.salt.ToString());

              if (descriptedPassword == userPassword)
                  return _currentUser;
              else
                  return recordEnum.invalidPassword  ????
          }

      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          Mercentwarehousecms
              .Logging
              .ExceptionUtility
              .LogErrorMessage("isValidUser Error DB Context", ex, "~");
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `isValidUser` name sounds like it should return `bool`.
2. My suggestion is to create new class

   public sealed UserValidationResult
   {
      public User User  { get; set; }
      public LoginStatus Status { get; set; }
   }

And modify your method to return `UserValidationResult` like

```
public UserValidationResult CheckUser(string userName, string userPassword)
{
  var user = GetUser(username, userPassword);
  return user != null ? 
       new UserValidationResult { Status = LoginStatus.Sucess, User = user }
     : new UserValidationResult { Status = LoginStatus.Failed; }
}
```

Comment: another we question I need to keep track of who is administrators and who is not what is the best way to do that i can access it on any page

Answer (score 1):

Add an `out` parameter:

```
public user isValidUser(string username, string userPassword, out LoginStatus loginStatus)
{
...
}

enum LoginStatus
{
  success,
  badPassword,
  badUsername
}
```

So, in your code set the value of `loginStatus` to reflect what happened.  Usually I'll set the return value to null if there is a problem and describe the problem with the `enum`.

Call the method like this:

```
LoginStatus result;
user userResult = isValidUser(username, password, out result);//Be sure to use the word "out" before your paramter
if (result == LoginStatus.success)
  {//Yay!}
else if (result == LoginStatus.badPassword)
  {//awww...}
else if (result == LoginStatus.badUsername)
  {//awww...}
```

Comment: see above plz  how do i retrieve the out parameter aand how best to call this method now

Comment: @StreetHawk msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx This explains everything ;)

Comment: @StreetHawk I made an edit to answer your follow up question.  BTW, you shouldn't make changes to an answer unless you are enhancing the answer (i.e. don't make changes to ask a follow up).